# Google Sheet / Excel - Use formula as the cell row for parent formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

E.g
`Cell M25` has the value 10:

```
=Init_Data!K CELL(M25)
```

would say:

```
=Init_Data!K10
```

I've Googled hard for this but it's such a weird one to explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDIRECT ("Init_Data!K"&M25)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a quirky question to ask and find answers for!

Answer (score 1):

INDIRECT is Volaitle and in this instance you can use INDEX instead which is not:

```
=INDEX(Init_Data!$K:$K,M25)
```